# Rewrite URL with .htaccess and exclude files

Tags: .htaccess

i have this piece of code in .htaccess file to rewrite URLS from upper case to lower case :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

My question is, how can i exclude files like .js, .css, and more from this rule?

My htaccess have other rules too:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another negative `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|ico|tiff)\s [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect all requests except if it ends with those extensions.

Comment: You are right mate, ok so the file have another rules, here is the rules:
I edited my post you can see other rules ...

Comment: But your htaccess is not showing the condition I suggested `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|ico|tiff)\s [NC]`

Comment: My bad i should put this line in two places, it works thank you!